# Installing Magento 2.0.10 security fix throws syntax error

Tags: magento2, upgrade, security

I installed the newest code base from Magento for the security update and now my site won't come up. When I look in the logs I see the following.

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

That's a core file that I have not touched, is this a PHP version issue or something else? Has anyone else had this issue?
Thanks,
JOse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` is an operator introduced in PHP version 5.6. It is also known as Splat Operator. Upgrading your PHP version should fix the error.